# Adding a close button to a JS accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a close button within the panel div of this accordion, I tried searching, but none of the suggestions work on this particular code. I am a noob.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: my code is identical to the one i posted, If you could give me an example on that one, I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would remove the JS you have there and use jQuery `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`. For what you want to achieve, it'd be much easier. `fadeIn()` `.panel` on click and `fadeOut()` `.panel` on click. Add some sort of close element to the HTML for the `fadeOut()` to work off.

```js
$('.accordion').click(function() {
  $('.panel').fadeIn();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.panel').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #000;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    display: none;
}

.close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="close">Close</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Is this a basic idea of what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you, exactly what I am looking for. So there is no way of keeping the same animation (instead of fade) and add that close button, just like you posted?

Comment: I'm trying to upvote your post, but apparently I don't have enough rep in order to do so, my appologies.

Comment: I tried this, and it works, but accordion stops working after I use the button

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
     panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.panel').toggle("active");
});
</script>